# email validation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, form-control

i am trying to add validation to email.

Structure : using reactive form, get email and check if already exist using filter javascript.

component.ts:

```
  isUniqueEmail(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl):  any | null => {
      if(control.value.email != null){
      this.httpService
      .getDataFromServer("api/employees?company_branch=" +this.user.branch_id)
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        var data = resp.data.employee;
        
        const found = data.filter(v => v.email == control.value.email);
  
        if(found.length !== 0){
          console.log("found one");
          return {exist: true}
        }
      });
      }
    }
  }
```

if email already exist console.log print found and every thing work fine.

declaration of form control:

```
  this.employeeForm = new FormGroup({

    email: new FormControl(null,
       [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$"),
      ValidatorsSettings.notOnlyWhitespace,
       ]),

  ),{validators: this.isUniqueEmail()}}
```

in html :

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="from-group">
              <label for="Email"> Email </label>
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>

              <input
                type="text"
                id="Email"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="email"
              />

              <div *ngIf="employeeForm.get('email').invalid && (employeeForm.get('email').touched || employeeForm.get('email').dirty)" class="help-block">
                <div *ngIf="employeeForm.get('email').errors.required || employeeForm.get('email').errors.notOnlyWhitespace" class="help-block">
                    Email is required
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="employeeForm.get('email').errors.pattern" class="help-block">
                    Email must be a valid email address format
                </div>

                <mat-error *ngIf="employeeForm.errors?.exist" class="help-block"
                >Email Already Exist</mat-error>

            </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

error not showing ! what i do wrong ?

Comment: I'm reasonable sure that *returning* a value does nothing; you need to change the app state. Like `this.whatever.exists = true` where `this` refers to the component

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, can you update my solution? @ChrisG

Comment: Replace `return {exist: true}` with `this.employeeForm.errors.exist = true;`

Comment: also not work @ChrisG

Comment: i receive this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'exist')

Comment: Right, try `this.employeeForm.errors = { exist: true };`

Answer (score 0):

Since the validator is using a service to request the response it should be an [asyncValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator). The code could end up as:

```
 isUniqueEmail(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors>=> {
      if(control.value.email != null){
        return this.httpService
        .getDataFromServer("api/employees?company_branch="+this.user.branch_id).pipe(
        .map((resp) => {
           var data = resp.data.employee;
           const found = data.filter(v => v.email == control.value.email);
           if(found.length !== 0){
             console.log("found one");
             return {exist: true}
           }
        });
      } 
      else return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i receive this error: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ValidationErrors>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740) @Ruina

Comment: Sorry @mesterlio, I missed the subscribe. I edited the answer. Again the code provided was to point you into what I think is the right direction to solve the problem. Please review the official documentation provided to make an implementation that fits you.

Comment: not work @Ruina